# Setting Ionic tabBadge with input variable

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I need to use a ngClass to make a notification badge behavior on my web page. 
If i use this:

```
<ion-tab [root]="tabPage2" tabTitle="Em Andamento" tabIcon="qi-th-list" tabBadgeStyle="danger" tabBadge=2> </ion-tab>
```

I'm trying to make some like this:

```
<ion-tab [root]="tabPage2" tabTitle="Em Andamento" tabIcon="qi-th-list" tabBadgeStyle="danger" [ngClass]="{ 'tabBadge={{tripsCount}}': tripsCount > 0 }"> </ion-tab>
```

But of course, it doesn't work.

How can I make this badge show the number of trips only when tripsCount greater than zero with Angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `tabBadge` attribute on an Ionic tab with this data binding syntax:

```
<ion-tab [tabBadge]="tripsCount" ...></ion-tab>
```

or this one:

```
<ion-tab tabBadge="{{tripsCount}}" ...></ion-tab>
```

The code can be tested in [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-vv7y6l). The number of trips is displayed at the bottom right. It is initialized at zero and starts being incremented after 3 seconds. The value is visible when it is 1 or more.

Comment: With the first option using <ion-tab [tabBadge]="tripsCount" ...></ion-tab> work like a charme, when zero the badge don't render.

Answer (score 0):

In the object that you pass to ngClass the key is the name of the class and you can have a javascript expression as the value:

```
[ngClass]="{'tabBadge': tripsCount > 0 }"
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you said.